# In encountering a draw by [x number of moves], when does the draw actually occur?

Tags: draw

I played a game of chess recently where we agreed to a rules modification: When one player was reduced to a lone King, a draw could be declared after 16 moves without capture/Pawn move. During this game, the player with material delivered checkmate on move 16. So what happens? Does the checkmate count first, or does the draw?

Comment: If you agree on a special rule, it's difficult for a third party to know what has been agreed. The official limit is 50 moves (for both sides), and a similar case (100th half-move resulting in a mate) is addressed e.g. in my [answer](http://chess.stackexchange.com/a/2908/1761) to another question: it is a mate, because the draw can be claimed only by a player having the move and the losing player has no move after the mate.

Answer (score 4):

Typically for the 50 move rule it's 50 ply from both sides without a pawn move or capture so the claim can only be made AFTER 50 moves.  The position on the board always stands so checkmate is checkmate.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, checkmate, the agreed upon stalemate was "AFTER" the 16th move. The opponent was mated on the 16th move, so checkmate.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with stalemate.